# CSS Layout Menu positioning?

Tags: html, css

Hi i am new to CSS and i don't quite understand why my menu displays like that and not on the same line.
Can somebody explain me why it does not displays on the same line? Here is the code

**CSS**

```
#cap { 
text-color:black;
font-size: 20px;
height:100px;    
}

#cap > #capcadru {
width:800px;
margin: 0px auto;
}

#cap > #capcadru > #cap2 {
  height:50px;
  text-align:center;
  border: 1px solid grey
}
#cap > #capcadru > #cap3{
 margin: 0px auto;
}
#cap > #capcadru > #cap3 > #cap3s {
  margin-right:400px;
  border: 1px solid red; 
  height:50px; 
  overflow:hidden;
}
#cap > #capcadru > #cap3 > #cap3s > div {
   text-align:center;
}
#cap > #capcadru > #cap3 > #cap3d {
   margin-left:400px; 
   border: 1px solid red; 
   height: 50px;}
#cap > #capcadru > #cap3 > #cap3d > div {
   text-align:right;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="cap">
  <div id="capcadru">
    <div id="cap2">Test</div>
    <div id="cap3">
      <div id="cap3s"><div>s</div></div>
      <div id="cap3d"><div>s</div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your CSS is a perfect example of an overkill!! :\

Comment: @NoobEditor Well explain to me what's that

Comment: No i just want to learn CSS and i was thinking about this menu but i can't make this work

Comment: First thing - step away from the IDs and the immediate selectors ( > ) , there's really no need for it for what you're trying to achieve - here's a basic menu you could tinker with http://jsfiddle.net/evanbriggs/q5c5hbwf/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is supported by IE8 and above!

If you are learning, then, google for `CSS tables` (*not HTML table*)

[**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nkznmcye/1/)

- remove `margin left / tight`

**Concerned CSS :**

```
#cap > #capcadru > #cap3 {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width:100%; /* added */
    display:table /* added */
}
#cap > #capcadru > #cap3 > #cap3s {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height:50px;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:50%; /* added */
    display:table-cell /* added */
}
#cap > #capcadru > #cap3 > #cap3s > div {
    text-align:center;
}
#cap > #capcadru > #cap3 > #cap3d {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 50px;
    width:50%; /* added */
    display:table-cell /* added */
}
```

Comment: `#cap > #capcadru > #cap3 > #cap3s`... that... is a tad redundant :)

Comment: @misterManSam : not only this, lots of others things are redundant,like i said in my comment under question, its and overkill....but then again, i am not cleaning css here, just showing a solution!! :)

Answer (score 0):

By default a  element uses the 'block' display method.  You can make div's display on the same line by using the display of inline or inline-block.

It may help to look at bootstrap if you you want to quickly perform layout as your require.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Comment: Still not working ,maybe you should try my code to see what it's about.

Answer (score 0):

Just some things which help you to write better and valied code:

1. You need to move your html to the body tag
2. You need to put the title into the head tag (its the tab name)
3. You need to add to the css-style the style: `type="text/css"`
4. `#` defines an ID, and ID should be always unique, you should use classes which can be selected by a `.` at css files (however i will do it now with ids that you can easier track the difference from your code ;-))

`

```
<html>
    <head>
       <title>Invat</title>
       <style type="text/css">
         CSS goes here
       </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="cap">
        <div id="capcadru">
          <div id="cap2">Test</div>
          <div id="cap3">
            <div id="cap3s"><div>s</div></div>
            <div id="cap3d"><div>s</div></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now we can look at your css:

```
#cap { text-color:black;font-size: 20px;height:100px; }
#cap > #capcadru {width:800px;margin: 0px auto; }
#cap > #capcadru > #cap2 {height:50px; text-align:center; border: 1px solid grey}
#cap > #capcadru > #cap3 {margin: 0px; auto }
#cap > #capcadru > #cap3 > #cap3s {margin-right:400px; border: 1px solid red; height:50px; overflow:hidden;}
#cap > #capcadru > #cap3 > #cap3s > div {text-align:center;}
#cap > #capcadru > #cap3 > #cap3d {margin-left:400px; border: 1px solid red; height: 50px;}
#cap #capcadru #cap2,  #cap #capcadru #cap3, #cap #capcadru #cap3 {text-align:right;}
```

By default the browser defines `display: block` to align multiply items next to each other, you need to change the display type to: `display: inline-block` and add to the items a `float: left`
So it would be in your case something like:

```
#cap #capcadru #cap2, #cap #capcadru #cap3 { display: inline-block; float: left; }
```

However here is a js fiddle with a clear html and css: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m60Lvny5/)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You must modify two blocks of your CSS like this.

```
#cap > #capcadru > #cap3 > #cap3s {
    width: 396px;
    border: 1px solid red; 
    height:50px; 
    overflow:hidden;
    float: left;
}

#cap > #capcadru > #cap3 > #cap3d {
    width: 396px;
    border: 1px solid red; 
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
}
```

**FIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/u0zpvjx9/